# Rails active admin: custom filter on table_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filtering, activeadmin

I've got a table_for like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Reports" do

menu priority: 2, label: I18n.t('active_admin.reports')

content title: I18n.t("active_admin.reports") do
    columns do
        column do 
            panel I18n.t('active_admin.bookings') do
                paginated_collection(Booking.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?",(params[:date_first].nil? or params[:date_first].empty? ? "2013-01-01" : params[:date_first]),(params[:date_last].nil? or params[:date_last].empty? ? Time.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").to_s : params[:date_last])).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(15)) do
                    table_for collection do |booking|
                        column('Date')         { |b| b.date }
                        column('Id')           { |b| b.id   }
                        column('Name')         { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.name }
                        column('Gender')       { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.gender }
                        column("Age")          { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.age }
                        column('Age min')      { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.age_min }
                        column('Age max')      { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.age_max }
                        column('Note')         { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.note }
                        column('Religion')     { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.religion }
                        column('Religionsens') { |b| b.captain.nil? ? '' : b.captain.religionsens }
                        column('Smeeting ID')  { |b| b.smeeting.nil? ? '' : b.smeeting.id }
                        column('Paiement')     { |b| BookingPayment.where(booking_id:b.id).sum(:type_cd) }
                        column('Amis')         { |b| BookingPayment.where("booking_id=? AND profile_id!=?", b.id, b.owner_id).count}
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end 
end
end
```

I'd like to allow filtering on this table, using the field 'created_at'. Defaults_action tag doesn't work, nor filter:

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: can you please share the entire Active Admin page?

Comment: Yep, post has been edited!